# How to sync the time on a remote linux host with time on local host

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

So I'm able to run the following command manually no problem on local host. The command will sync the time on the remote host with that of local host:

`ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx "date --set \"$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")\""`

(The 2nd `date` will get the current time on local host and the 1st `date` will set the time on the remote host.)

However, I need to automate this process(in c++ code, see below), so I need to use `sshpass` to help me with password, so I have something like this:

`sshpass -p \'xxxxxxx\' ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@xxx.xx.xx.xx \"date --set \"$(date -u +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\")\"\"`

But this command does not work. (I guess one of problems is that the 2nd `date` in the command doesn't get to run on local host but it should)

How can I make it work?

**NOTE: there is no `ntp` on the remote host.**

EDIT:

so I updated that cmd to this:

`TIME=$(date -u +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"); sshpass -p 'xxxxxxxx' ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@xxx.xx.xx.xx date --set \"$TIME\"` but still doesn't work.

I need to run this cmd in c++ code so the complete code is like this:

`system("TIME=$(date -u +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"); sshpass -p 'xxxxxxx' ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@xxx.xx.xx.xx date --set \"$TIME\"");`

Comment: Why are you escaping all the quotes?

Comment: @glennjackman I need to issue this cmd in cpp code, so I have to put it into `system()` in cpp code and treat it as a string. Sorry I didn't make it clear in the question

Comment: Why aren't you just using NTP and doing it properly? If you don't have NTP then either install it or ask your system administrators to do so. For a machine connected to a network it should be an obvious solution

Comment: @roaima The reality is that there is no ntp on the remote host... I have to deal with it sorry, ntp is not possible here.

Comment: Henry, I can see you're saying there is no NTP. I'm suggesting you try to address that. If the server is outside your systems management then ask the systems administrator (or submit a change request to your Change Board) to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simplify it.

`ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx date --set @$(date -u +%s)`

The `$(date +%s)` gets the seconds since 1/1/1970 and the `@` tells date to expect the date format to be in seconds since 1/1/1970

EDIT:
You mentioned in a comment that this needs to be in a string and will be executed in cpp code using `system()`. If thats the case you can just use `time()` to construct the string instead of passing `$(date +%s)` to the shell.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works in my case. The whole line of code for me is: `system("sshpass -p 'xxxxxxx' ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@xxx.xx.xx.xx date --set @$(date -u +%s)");`